# Doctrine One-To-One bidirectional relationship CASCADE direction

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, doctrine

I have two doctrine entities (User and DatiFiscali) defined with the yaml annotations as below.

What I am trying to achieve is when deleting *User* to also have *DatiFiscali* deleted on cascade,

however with the configuration below I can only obtain the opposite behaviour: when deleting *DatiFiscali*, *User* will also be removed on cascade.

I can easily obtain the desired result by manually adding the following foreign key:

```
CONSTRAINT `datifiscali_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `User` (`datifiscali_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

However when updating the schema using 'docrine orm:schema-tool:update ' doctrine rightly will try to DROP the the foreign key above.

Is in any way possible to achieve the above without:

- changing the relationship direction.
- having to use custom sql rather than relying on doctrine orm:schema-tool:create

**Entity A:**

```
Test\User:
    type: entity
    table: User
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        username:
            type: text
            nullable: true
        email:
            type: text
            nullable: true

    oneToOne:
        datiFiscali:
            targetEntity: DatiFiscali
            inversedBy: user
            joinColumns:
                datifiscali_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
                    onDelete: CASCADE
```

**Entity B:**

```
Test\DatiFiscali:
    type: entity
    table: DatiFiscali
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO

    fields:
        name:
            type: text
            nullable: true
        surname:
            type: text
            nullable: true
        business_name:
            type: text
            nullable: true

    oneToOne:
        user:
            targetEntity: User
            mappedBy: datiFiscali
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try with `cascade: [remove]`. But I'm not sure on which side it should be defined in this case. Probably in `DatiFiscali`.  More info: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

Comment: Thank you for the advice @dragoste, surprisinigly I have tried _cascade: [remove]_ in both files without any result: no cascade delete takes place on the orm level.

Comment: @Davide You need to specify the `onDelete: CASCADE` on the attribute user of your class `DatiFiscali`. As it is right now, your are saying "on DatiFiscali deletion delete the user pls", but you want to say "on User deletion, delete the DatiFiscali pls"

Comment: Ok, I have tried this as well apparently in a oneToOne relation when the 'mappedBy' attribute is defined any 'joinColumn' property is ignored. By commenting mappedBy instead doctrine propose the following change:

Comment: `ALTER TABLE DatiFiscali ADD user_id INT DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE DatiFiscali ADD CONSTRAINT FK_7A2A1DE5A76ED395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_7A2A1DE5A76ED395 ON DatiFiscali (user_id);`

which means that the schema will now have an additional 'user_id' column (double indexes for the same relation).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put cascade option in the right place:

```
oneToOne:
    datiFiscali:
        targetEntity: DatiFiscali
        inversedBy: user
        joinColumns:
            datifiscali_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
        cascade: ["remove"]
```